# How to draw a Triangle of the middle in the Border

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to use WPF draw a Border which has a Triangle in it.

Is that possible to do?

[image]

The Triangle is always on the bottom of the middle in the Border. The border **width size is dynamic**.

**Update:**

I tried, But I don't know how to display Triangle on the Border.
Here is my example:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
        <Border Width="200" Height="80" CornerRadius="20" Background="Red"></Border>
</Grid>
```

And my result:

[image]

Comment: WPF can draw pretty much anything you want it to. What have _you_ tried? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Though its not the answer you are looking for, you can use the `Callout` Control in Blend SDK. It will save a lot of your time. A related [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/eda428/use-of-callout-shapes-and-text-property-in-expression-blend/). If you don't have Blend installed, I guess you can add reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing` dll and use the `Callout` control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw almost any shape using polygon.
This is what I think you wanted :)

```
<Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="20" Background="Red" Margin="0,0,0,30"></Border>
    <Polygon Margin="0,0,50,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="50"
        Height="30"
        Points="0,0 2,0 1,1"
        Fill="Red"
        Stretch="Fill"
        StrokeThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I see. we need draw 2 different part. Thank you very much.